# Angular app displays black screen after splash screen in iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, plugins, splash-screen, statusbar

I have built an Angular app for Android and iOS. It also uses jQuery and jStorage. It's a Cordova app built using Visual Studio 14.

I have added the statusbar and splashscreen plugins to config.xml. I have set fullscreen to Yes.

I have created all the different splash screens for different screen resolutions.

After the splashscreen loads, the app displays a blank black screen. If you rotate it from portrait mode to landscape mode, the app displays correctly.

(I looked at all the other questions where people had a similar issue, and none of them had exactly the same issue, or an answer that I could use.)

Comment: I have this SAME problem. Rotating the app makes it work. Did you resolve it?

Comment: I think we did. Try putting this at the end of your `config.xml` file:   `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.3.0" />
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="False" />`

Comment: I'm still having issues.  Tried many different variations of the cordova plugin whitelist in confix.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this at the end of your config.xml file: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.3.0" /> <preference name="Fullscreen" value="False" />`